# NoReverseMatch Error Reverse for 'profile' with no arguments not found

Tags: python, django

Please somebody anybody help please, know that these question has been answered a lot of times but am new to django and don't know how to get around this in my code. Am following a tutorial and that builds a vlog with django. Everythin works fine but then i wanted to modify it and dispaly the posts written by a user aon their profile page so that others can see it. i passed a variable to the original url that lead to the page and then also modify my views that only rendered a html template to include posts from the user. it works the post are listed the way i want but after i go to the update profile page and update on submit the button that was supposed to redirect to the profile page returns an error

```
NoReverseMatch at /update_profile/
Reverse for 'profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$']
```

My urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/<str:username>/', user_views.profile, name = 'profile'),
    path('update_profile/', user_views.update_profile, name='update_profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

this is my views.py file

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from blog.models import Post

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'{username} Your account has been created! Login to verify your account')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def profile(request, username):
    user_posts = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user).order_by('-date_posted')
    context = {
        'user_posts': user_posts
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)

def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES,
        instance=request.user)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/update_profile.html', context)
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

i have two apps users and blogs if there is anything more you need please let me know.
I also want to make it so that the profile can be viewed by anonymous users

Comment: Probably in one of your templates you're calling `profile` URL without passing the `username` param.

Answer (score 0):

in "update_profile" function of your views.py, instead of **return redirect('profile')** do something like this:

```
return redirect(reverse('profile', kwargs={"username": request.user}))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @zero. my problem is solved. works like magic. i knew it had something to do with that redirect just didn't know how to handle it. Thank you so much. You just saved me a lot of headache